# Getting Perl to return the correct exit code

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 11.04.  I want Perl to execute a shell script and exit with the same code the shell script exits.  But this isn't working for me ...

```
    system($runCmd) or die("Failed to run \"$runCmd\": $!");
```

I have confirmed that running the "$runCmd" by itself returns an exit code of 255, but the "die" clause isn't getting invoked.  How do I exit with the correct code or at least fail for non-success codes?

Another minor requirement is that I want the output from $runCmd to be printed to the screen.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As [`perldoc -f die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) says, `die` doesn't give a specific exit code (only a nonzero exit code).  To get what you want, you'll need something like:

```
my $exit_code=system($runCmd);

if($exit_code!=0)
{
  print "Command $runCmd failed with an exit code of $exit_code.\n";
  exit($exit_code >> 8);
}
else
{
  print "Command $runCmd successful!\n";
}
```

Comment: The value returned from `system()` is an integer which encodes the exit value of the child process plus flags indicating how the child process exited (normal termination, killed by a signal, etc.)
The value passed to `exit()` is just the exit value.

Comment: Right, the OP wants "Perl to execute a shell script and exit with the same code the shell script exits", and hence passing `$exit_code` to `exit()` makes the program exit with the same exit code as the exit code generated by passing `$runCmd` to the shell.

Comment: The program /bin/false exits with exit value 1. But `perl -e 'print system("/bin/false")'` prints 256.

Comment: @user5402: Not necessarily. From the info: "Portable programs should not assume that the exit status of `false' is 1, as it is greater than 1 on some non-GNU hosts." And we all want portable programs, don't we? :)

Comment: @musicKk I was just pointing out that the value returned by `system()` is 256 times the value you pass into `exit()`.

Comment: What passed through the mind of the man who decides to times 256 the return value when writing the system command ???

Answer (score 14):

If `system` returns `255`, you need an `and` conditional.

`system` returns zero on *successful* execution. Also, `die` will modify your script's exit code. Instead `warn` and return the last exit code like this:

```
system($cmd) and do {
    warn "Failed to run $cmd. Exit code is $?";
    exit $? >> 8;
};
```

In order to catch the program's output, use the backtick (`) operator:

```
my $output = `$cmd`;

if ($?) {
   warn ...;
   exit $? >> 8;
}
```

The backtick operator only captures `STDOUT`, so for all error messages (which usually go to `STDERR`) to be captured, modify `$cmd` and append `2>&1` to it.

Notice the right shift by eight bits on the `$?` global.

---

Credits go to @musiKk: The [perl documentation on `system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) states how to properly retrieve the *actual* exit status.

Comment: Just an addition: You have to shift the return value of `system` by eight to the right to get to the return value of `$cmd`. (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

Answer (score 6):

> ```
>   system($runCmd) or die("Failed to run \"$runCmd\": $!");
> ```

Unlike most Perl functions, `system` returns false when it succeeds and true when it fails.  This is completely backwards I know but it is just how it is.

You need "system() and" not "system() or".  And you probably want `$?` not `$!`, although this can sometimes be tricky.

I have a minor aversion to

```
system(...)                           && die
```

because it screws up all the rest of `|| die`’s that normally make a continuous vertical double margin over on the right, I sometimes write

```
system(...) == 0                      || die
```

so that they all line up correctly again.

Answer (score 1):

If system()'s seeming backwardness bothers you, you can always make it more palatable by doing something like:

```
my $err = system '/something/that/may/not/work';
if ($err) {
    warn "@{[$! || 'undefined error']}\n";
    exit $err >> 8;
}
```

Your $runCmd, BTW, if it prints to the screen (and this is run from the command line and you haven't redirected the output, etc.) will print to the screen. It's just that IT will print it to the screen. Perl won't be responsible for that or know (or care) what it's printing. If that's all you want, and you don't want to systematically analyse or manipulate the output of $runCmd, you're golden. Try it:

```
perl -e "system 'ls -Fahl'"
```

It also won't interfere with your $runCmd's STDOUT either. That'll go to your terminal too. For instance:

```
$ perl -e "system 'ls -Fahl /dev/null/something' and die qq(fail: $! >> 8 == @{[$! >> 8]})"
ls: /dev/null/something: Not a directory
fail: 26205 >> 8 == 102 at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking the `$?` variable (a.k.a. `$CHILD_ERROR` is you `use English;` pun intended). This allows for a more thorough inspection of how your `system()` call turns out.

The thing to understand is that `$?` is a 16-bit word (art credit to [@ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244584/7314180)):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 15| 14| 13| 12| 11| 10|  9|  8|  7|  6|  5|  4|  3|  2|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

 \-----------------------------/ \-/ \-------------------------/
            Exit code            core     Signal that killed
            (0..255)            dumped         (0..127)
                                (0..1)
```

```perl
system($runCmd);
if ($? == -1) { # Failed to start program / error of the wait(2) system call
    die "Failed to execute '$runCmd': $!";
} elsif ($? & 127) { # Check for non-zero signal
    die "'$runCmd' died with signal", ($? & 127), ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without', " coredump";
} else { # No kill signal, check exit code.
    my $exit_code = $? >> 8; # This is the number you said to be 255.
    # print "'$runCmd' exited with value ", $exit_code, "\n";

    if ($exit_code == 255) {
        die("Failed to run \"$runCmd\": $!");
    } else {
        # can do additional checks for other exit codes if desired
    }
    exit $exit_code;
}
```

---

There is a noteworthy "alternative" if you really don't want to mess with `$?`. Basically, just use [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple). Note that it isn't a core module, so you need to install it.

Using it is simple:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system);  # system() will now die properly

my $exit_value = system($runCmd);
my $exit_value2 = system($runCmd,@args);  # Alternative form that avoids shell if @args
```

If you don't want to override `system` you could use `run` instead:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(run);

my $exit_value = run($runCmd);
my $exit_value2 = run($runCmd,@args);
```