# How perl get exit code from linux

Tags: linux, shell, perl

In my Perl, I want to use linux `merge` command and print its exit code:

```
system "merge $A $old $new";
print "exit code= $?\n";
```

And in linux manual, the exit code for `merge` command should be:

**Exit status is 0 for no conflicts, 1 for some conflicts, 2 for trouble.**

But in fact my result is :

**merge: warning: conflicts during merge**

**exit code= 256**

it looks like the exit code is "256" not "1".
Why cause this situation? and how can I get the correct exit code?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not look at the return value of `system()` itself?

Comment: @tadman, how to get return value?

Comment: Like `my $result = system(...)` presumably, just as you'd do with any variable.

Comment: The value `256` corresponds to hex 0x0100, and the upper byte is the exit status (in this case, status 1) and a non-zero lower byte indicates 'death from a signal' (the value indicating which signal and whether there was a core dump).  This is the way the `wait()` system call (and its relatives) gets the encoded exit status from a program on Unix-like systems.

Comment: See, for example, [Why does `wait()` set exit status to 256 instead of the exit -1 status of the forked process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3659616/15168) — a title which is slightly incoherent as 256 corresponds to exit status of +1, not -1.

Comment: oh OK!!!!!  I can understand now! thank you guys!

Comment: Notice that [`perldoc perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar) says of `$?`: _Finally, `$?` may be set to a non-0 value if the external program … fails. The upper eight bits reflect specific error conditions encountered by the program (the program's `exit()` value). The lower eight bits reflect mode of failure, like signal death and core dump information. See_ wait(2) _for details._  And [perldoc perlfunc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#system-LIST) says similarly: _The return value [of `system`] is the exit status of the program as returned by the wait call._

Comment: I think this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080434/getting-perl-to-return-the-correct-exit-code