# How I combine a bash hookscript with a Perl hookscript for use with Proxmox?

Tags: bash, perl, gpu, proxmox, virtio

I am trying to use Promox VE has the hypervisor for running VMs.

In one of my VMs, I have a hookscript that is written for the bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $2 == "pre-start" ]
then
echo "gpu-hookscript: Resetting GPU for Virtual Machine $1"
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/remove
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
fi
```

which is to help with enabling GPU passthrough.

And then I have another hookscript that is written in Perl, which enables virtio-fs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Exmple hook script for PVE guests (hookscript config option)
# You can set this via pct/qm with
# pct set <vmid> -hookscript <volume-id>
# qm set <vmid> -hookscript <volume-id>
# where <volume-id> has to be an executable file in the snippets folder
# of any storage with directories e.g.:
# qm set 100 -hookscript local:snippets/hookscript.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "GUEST HOOK: " . join(' ', @ARGV). "\n";
# First argument is the vmid
my $vmid = shift;
# Second argument is the phase
my $phase = shift;
if ($phase eq 'pre-start') {
# First phase 'pre-start' will be executed before the guest
    # ist started. Exiting with a code != 0 will abort the start
print "$vmid is starting, doing preparations.\n";
system('/var/lib/vz/snippets/launch-virtio-daemon.sh');
# print "preparations failed, aborting."
    # exit(1);
} elsif ($phase eq 'post-start') {
# Second phase 'post-start' will be executed after the guest
    # successfully started.
print "$vmid started successfully.\n";
} elsif ($phase eq 'pre-stop') {
# Third phase 'pre-stop' will be executed before stopping the guest
    # via the API. Will not be executed if the guest is stopped from
    # within e.g., with a 'poweroff'
print "$vmid will be stopped.\n";
} elsif ($phase eq 'post-stop') {
# Last phase 'post-stop' will be executed after the guest stopped.
    # This should even be executed in case the guest crashes or stopped
    # unexpectedly.
print "$vmid stopped. Doing cleanup.\n";
} else {
    die "got unknown phase '$phase'\n";
}
exit(0);
```

What would be the best way for me to combine these two files into a single format, so that I can use it as a hookscript in Proxmox?

I tried reading the thread here about how to convert a bash shell script to Perl, and not being a programmer, admittedly, I didn't understand what I was reading.

I appreciate the teams help in educating a non-programmer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

before

```
system('/var/lib/vz/snippets/launch-virtio-daemon.sh');
```

insert pls.

```
system('echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/remove');
system('echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan');
```

Had your original code above evaluated return code of these perl calls (it is not the case):

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/remove
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

you could apply solutions from:
[Getting Perl to return the correct exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080434/getting-perl-to-return-the-correct-exit-code)

Comment: Thank you.

But what I am trying to do is that I will need to do both, in the script.

I should be able to add those lines and have it execute all three lines, correct?

Comment: Answer 1 has been corrected. Daemon should be started not before your two "echo..." calls (and return code evaluation as needed.) Pls. forget about the previous code version.

Comment: Thank you.

I think just by chance, I ended up adding your lines ahead of the "system('/var/lib/vz/snippets/launch-virtio-daemon.sh');" per your revised answer.

That was just a fluke.

Thank you and I appreciate your help in regards to this.

I think that it looks like that it is working, at least for this aspect of it.