# Errors with git clone in perl script

Tags: git, perl

I am trying to write a Perl script that does git operations.  I am getting errors in the script when running it and it seems to be with the git clone line.  Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $url = "git\@devbitbucket.ethos.com:7999";

print "What is the project asset code? ";
chomp(my $projectcode = <> );
print "$projectcode\n";

print "What is the repository name? ";
chomp(my $reponame = <> );
print "$reponame\n";

chdir "cd /export/appl/bbdev/scripts/files/";
chdir;
print "git clone ssh://$url/$projectcode/$reponame.git\n";
system( 'git clone ssh://$url/$projectcode/$reponame.git $reponame' );
#$reponame =~ s/\..*//s;

chdir "cd $reponame";
chdir;
system( 'cp -p /export/appl/bbdev/scripts/files/* .' );
system( 'git status' );
system( 'git add -A && git commit -m "Default Repository Initial Files" ');
system( 'git push --all' );
system( 'git status' );

exit 0;
```

Error

```
git clone ssh://git@devbitbucket.ethos.com:7999/mikt/test2.git
fatal: No directory name could be guessed.
Please specify a directory on the command line
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /appl)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Answer (score 3):

A few issue immediately jump out

### String Interpolation not happening

This line uses a string enclosed in single quotes. Single quoted string do not interpolate Perl variables -- `$url`, `$projectcode`, etc in this case.

```
system( 'git clone ssh://$url/$projectcode/$reponame.git $reponame' );
```

You need to use double quotes to make that happen

```
system( "git clone ssh://$url/$projectcode/$reponame.git $reponame" );
```

### Incorrect use of `chdir`

There are a couple of places where `chdir` is called with a parameter.

```
chdir "cd /export/appl/bbdev/scripts/files/";
...
chdir "cd $reponame";
```

Both are failing silently (if you checked the return code it would be apparent). When the `chdir` function is given a parameter, it must be the name of a directory. You are passing strings with a "`cd` " prefix in both instances. These are non-existent directories.

You want this this

```
chdir "/export/appl/bbdev/scripts/files/"
    or die "Cannot chdir: $!\n";
...
chdir $reponame
    or die "Cannot chdir: $!\n";
```

The use of `chdir` without any parameter means "go to my home directory" (See [chdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir) for more details). You don't need these lines at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I really appreciate it.

When you say "if you checked the return code it would be apparent" what does that mean?  Is it this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080434/getting-perl-to-return-the-correct-exit-code or similar https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=486200?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, those answers are correct.